# Authentication Error when connecting to WMTS in DSM

Tags: qgis, wmts

I am relatively new to QGIS and use version 3.4.11 for a university project of Polish archaeological features.

I am trying to get the "Digital Elevation Model ISOK – Hillshade" WMTS Layer from "https://www.geoportal.gov.pl/uslugi/usluga-przegladania-wmts" working, but when I try to connect via the Data source Manager, it shows the error: "...failed: Host requires authentication". I use "http://mapy.geoportal.gov.pl/wss/service/WMTS/guest/wmts/ISOK_CIEN?SERVICE=WMTS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities" to connect to the server.

It worked very well before, but when I tried to connect today, the error appeared. What could be the problem?

Comment: Maybe the host now requires identification for that service.

Comment: That is what i fear. But Since the problem only crops up with the ISOK sources, i was hoping it was only a mistake in my request. I also found no notice about this on the rest of the website.

Comment: Currently it says "internal server error". Maybe wait a few days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ISOK layer links has changed since 15th October: [Istotne zmiany w danych i usługach związanych z Numerycznym Modelem Terenu](http://www.gugik.gov.pl/aktualnosci/15.10.2019-istotne-zmiany-w-danych-i-uslugach-zwiazanych-z-numerycznym-modelem-terenu)

For GetCapabilities request you can try this link:

http://mapy.geoportal.gov.pl/wss/service/PZGIK/NMT/GRID1/WMTS/ShadedRelief?SERVICE=WMTS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities

I don't use QGIS, I've tested this link only in a web browser - seems to work fine.